# How can I arbitrarily print Drupal's advanced node search form?

Tags: drupal, search, forms, drupal-6

I'd like to print Drupal's advanced node search form (the one that appears on search/node) in a template--let's say page.tpl.php for example.

This gets me the basic search box (without the "Advanced search" fieldset):

```
<?php
print drupal_get_form('search_form');
?>
```

However, the advanced search form's `$form_id` is also 'search_form'. The "advanced search" fieldset on search/node appears to be created by `node_form_alter()` in node.module, starting at line 1849. Is it possible to force `drupal_get_form()` to retrieve the version of the search_form that gets altered by  `node_form_alter()`? Or should I approach this another way entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try creating your own form and using the node form.

Something like:

`function my_form(..) {

  $form = search_form(..);

  return $form;

}`

For the arguments I left out, see:
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--search--search.module/function/search_form/6